# How to display date of blog creation

Tags: theme-development, date

Is it possible to display (in PHP) the year when the blog was created? I want use this in footer (copyright) on my several blogs with my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is possible if the first user account exists (with user id 1). Then you can use -

```
<?php echo mysql2date('Y', get_user_option('user_registered', 1) ); ?>
```

The concept behind this is, when a WordPress Blog Installed, one user account created, and we are using his/her registration time.

Comment: It works but I must replace `register_date` to `user_registered` ;)